# Why does calling this function change my array?

Tags: perl, arrays, file

Perl seems to be killing my array whenever I read a file:

```
my @files = ("foo", "bar", "baz");
print "Files: " . join(" ", @files) . "\n";

foreach(@files) {
   print "The file is $_\n";
   func();
}

sub func {
   open(READ, "< test.txt");
   while(<READ>) {
   }
   close READ;
}

print "Files: " . join(" ", @files) . "\n";
```

produces:

```
Files: foo bar baz
The file is foo
The file is bar
The file is baz
Files:
```

but when I comment out `func()`, it gives what I would've expected:

```
Files: foo bar baz
The file is foo
The file is bar
The file is baz
Files: foo bar baz
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to change `foo` to localize `$_`, or not to use `$_` in your loop. Best yet, do both:

```
foreach my $filename (@files) {
    print "The file is $filename\n";
    func();
}

sub func {
    local $_;
    open my $read, '<', 'test.txt' or die "Couldn't open test.txt: $!";
    while(<$read>) {
    }
    close $read or die "Couldn't close file: $!";
}
```

The foreach loop aliases `$_` to the current name of the file and the `while(<READ>)` assigns to `$_`. That's a bad combination of magic, so to say.

In general, it's a bad idea to rely on much on `$_` for anything other than a one-liner.

Comment: my $_; (5.10+ only) is a better way to do it

Comment: True, but distributions are only beginning to move to 5.10. I assume people are still on 5.8 for the most part.

Comment: Brad: that is correct, but personally I'm only using it since last week, so I'm not assuming other people are also using it. My Debian machines don't have it yet, for example. For that matter, plenty of people are still stuck on Perl 5.6 :-|.